How to create own nuget package based on polly 7.2.4 .NET with new name and packageId
I tried to create own nuget package based on polly 7.2.4 .NET with new name and packageId. In most cases you need just change PackageId and pack the project. But it looks like Polly library has reference on himself. Because when I changed PackageIr or project name ("PollyTest"), I see the errors:

Error NU1101  Unable to find package PollyTest. No packages exist with this id in source(s): NuGet    Polly   [path where project is located]\Polly.csproj
Or in other case
Error MSB4018 : The "Microsoft.DotNet.ApiCompat.Task.ValidatePackageTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Package 'C:\Users[USER].nuget\packages\polly\7.2.3\polly.7.2.3.nupkg' not found. Please provide a valid package path.

Library references:
https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly
https://www.nuget.org/packages/polly/
I'm work with Polly 7.2.4 (not the latest)

Why do you want to create your own package from Polly?

Our samples in the repo reference the published version of the NuGet package, hence the compilation error. You'd need to remove that, but why do you feel you need to make a copy of Polly in the first place? We also use NuGet package validation analysers, which again compare against the published NuGet package - that won't work unless it's removed/turned-off either.

Shortly, I need to create fork from Polly 7.2.4 and use it not from nuget store, but from our azure artifacts to avoid conflicts with different plugins. So I need package of Polly with different name.

From the scant details you've provided, that doesn't sound like it's going to be the fix you think it will be. But if you want to press ahead anyway, you'll need to change more things in your fork to fix the errors to remove or turn off the things I mentioned.

Also, there errors you're getting are nothing to do with building NuGet packages. You're getting errors from the project's own compilation setup because your renaming is breaking it - you'll need to fix that in your own copy.

Thank you for anwer! @MartinCostello Could you please provide more details?
I turned off code analyzers. What else should I change? Which files edit?

To create a NuGet package with a new name and package id:

Turn off analyzers.targets:
<PropertyGroup>
  <RunAnalyzers>false</RunAnalyzers>
  <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>false</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
  <AnalysisLevel>latest</AnalysisLevel>
  <EnableNETAnalyzers>false</EnableNETAnalyzers>
</PropertyGroup>


Turn off NuGet package validation (Library.targets)


    <PropertyGroup Label="NuGet package validation">
      <EnablePackageValidation Condition="'$(EnablePackageValidation)' == ''">false</EnablePackageValidation>
    </PropertyGroup>


Add own info in Polly.csproj (and into Polly.Core.csproj if need)

    <AssemblyTitle>PollyTest</AssemblyTitle>
    <AssemblyName>PollyTest</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>PollyTest</PackageId>

